# IIS 6 not reading config file for my angular app

Tags: angular, iis-6

i am deploying an angular app in iis 6 and i found a webconfig file online of which i added to my app. The problem is with refreshing: i get a 404 error message i cannot understand why as this is supposed to work.

web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/clientPortal/" />
      <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and in my angular-cli.json i included this file and placed it under src where the angular-cli.json is

```
   "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.png",
        "help",
        "styles.css",
        "web.config"
      ],
```

I am finding it very hard to get to the bottom of what the error could be. Please advise anyone

Comment: Do you have `<base href="/">` in your `index.html`?

Comment: yes and here is it is i set this when doin the build

Comment: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>IST - Client Portal</title><base href="/clientPortal/">.....

Comment: Yes i do and it seems that when i run the following command: ng build --prod --base-href=/myapp/ --aot= false... the resulting output in my dist folder has an index.html  file with the sample output (html) i have provided above, i alsso added a service that makes it possible to change my config after deployement.